# Set times that windows can wake up for updates

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I have seen many posts about how to fix windows waking up from sleep for updates. However, all of the answers I've seen involve disabling this task. I don't want to completely disable it, I want to set a time range where it's allowed to wake up so it doesn't run while I'm trying to fall asleep. Is this possible?

This is what I get from running `powercfg /waketimers`:

```
Timer set by [SERVICE] \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\svchost.exe (SystemEventsBroker) expires at 1:53:59 AM on 6/7/2019.
  Reason: Windows will execute 'NT TASK\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot_AC' scheduled task that requested waking the computer.
```

Thanks